# Is there a way to sandbox or hard contain a part of a web page?

Tags: html, iframe

I am writing an app where users will be able to create html content to place in an area on the page. I am not worried about bad actors (they would screw themselves) but I am worried about people making dumb mistakes like having an additional `</div>` that then honks up the rest of the page content.

If what they create is a distinct html document (it isn't) I could use an `<iframe>`. So is there ay way to achieve this?

Comment: so use a sandboxed iframe and let them mess up the html in there. It won't flow out into your main document.

Comment: @epascarello That might work. I could deliver their html as a "file" from my app. Good idea - thanks